# HTML Bootstrap date default as last day of previous month

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, date, default

I have an operation that we run on a monthly basis, with an as_of_dt as the last calendar day of a month.

I have a working date selector on my dashboard, but I currently have a default date hardcoded. I'd like to make it default to the last calendar day of the previous month. So, for the month of june 2017, I want it to default to 5-31-2017.

Here is my current html:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="mr-sm-2" for="date_input">Date</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="date" value="2017-05-31" id="date_input" name='date_input'>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Once the page has been loaded you can dynamically calculate the last day of the month and assign it to your input element. I'll add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically calculate the last day of the month and assign it to your input element.

```html
<input type="date" id="date">
<script>
  function getLastDayDate() {
    var today = new Date();
    var lastDayDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 0);
    var year = lastDayDate.getFullYear();
    var month = lastDayDate.getMonth().length == 2 ? lastDayDate.getMonth() + 1 : '0' + (lastDayDate.getMonth() + 1);
    var date = lastDayDate.getDate();
    document.getElementById("date").value = [year, month, date].join('-');
  }
  getLastDayDate();
</script>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your suggestion exactly, but this is what I got:

Comment: I guess it isn't possible to add a screenshot?  I got "date: mm/dd/yyyy" -

Comment: The id you provided in your code example is `date_input`. Are you sure you're using my date input that has an id of `date` or your original input? If so, change the id from `date` to `date_input`. I transformed my answer into a fiddle. you can run the code and see the expected output.

Comment: This is what I have before your script:  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="mr-sm-2" for="date_input">Date</label>
      <input class="form-control">
    <input type="date" id="date">

Comment: Now I  have a bar where one could enter text to the right of the date. The date defaults to 5/30 instead of 5/31

Comment: The bar seems to be your `<input class="form control">` What is the purpose of that line? It just seems like an empty input tag. Maybe you can remove it? I fixed the bug with the wrong date.

Comment: I don't know exactly what it does, but deleting it breaks things D:

Comment: It's a form where you select a few attributes (including date) and then show several calculations. Deleting '''<input class="form control"> ''' seems to have made the "execute" button disappear among other things

Comment: @ifthenifthen I apologize--I can't help you there as I don't have bootstrap experience. That may be another question you can ask on stack overflow. However the above code does solve the problem of having the input element default to the last day of the previous month.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'll